# Warning: Missing argument 1 for Drupal\custom_forms\Service\CustomFormsService::__construct() in Drupal forms

Tags: php, drupal

I receiving the following warning in my code.

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for
>   Drupal\custom_forms\Service\CustomFormsService::__construct(), called
>   in
>   /drupal/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php
>   on line 264 and defined in
>   Drupal\custom_forms\Service\CustomFormsService->__construct() (line 13
>   of modules/custom_forms/src/Service/CustomFormsService.php).

And my code is

```
public function __construct($request) {

    $this->cityname = \Drupal::request()->get('cityname');

    if($this->cityname != ''){
    $result = \Drupal::database()->select('city_municipality','cm')
      ->fields('cm',array('municipality'))
      ->condition('city', $this->cityname)
      ->execute()->fetchAll();
      $result = json_encode($result);

      print $result; 
      exit;
    }
  }
```

The forms works fine but the warning message shows...Can anyone help me out